# Azure-CLI commands not working

Tags: azure

I have a couple commands failing on Azure-CLI.

For example, the following:

$ azure webapp config hostnames list --resource-group resgr1 --name vrtestapp

...says "error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

(And an "hostnames add" also fails with "error: Object www.myurl.com has no method 'format', so I cannot add nor view my vhosts..)

And then I have this:

$ azure network nic create \
--name nic1 \
--resource-group resgr1 \
--location westeurope \
--private-ip-address 10.42.42.100 \
--public-ip-name pubip1  \
--subnet-id /subscriptions/56a13ec6-eee2-46df-8753-b2aaa83d5efd/resourceGroups/resgr1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1

...which says  "error:   Cannot parse the request."

I'm just starting out with this tool, information online seems sparse..

Can you help me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure that your Azure-Cli is latest.

The latest version for now is 0.10.7. To install the latest version of Azure-Cli, please refer this [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/)

Second, please make sure that the Azure-Cli is in ARM mode. Your commands are all ARM commands.

To configure the Azure-Cli working in ARM mode, please run the following command:

**azure config mode arm**